# How do i get data from multiple sockets in one node to another socket in another node

Tags: socket.io-redis

Basically my problem is mentioned in the image below at (4) but im trying to retrieve information that is held in sockets in a different node, how do i retrieve data from sockets in a different node?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
// sending to individual socketid (private message)
  socket.to(socketid).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```

but the one thing im curious about is whether this will work between the sockets placed in the different nodes, I'm guessing that it will.

Answer (score 1):

The figure itself gives you the answer
If you look closely
client 1 requests info from all the other clients
client 2 3 4 all go to node 2 in side and outside of the frame.
the originally requested data can be done by node 1 and node 2 to client 1 and clients 2 3 4 respectively.

Comment: so basically what your saying is to call a broadcast.emit so that client 1 can retrieve that data back to itself? i can see this working 

but what if i want that data stored inside of node1 specifically to the same socket on node1?

Comment: also from my understanding is that each client is connected to their respective nodes in a 1:1 relationship, so if the client calls socket.emit then the data will be sent back to the respective node where the socket resides, so how do i send the data to another socket that resides in another node?